# Exclude some indexes from elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

I am using **_all** as index pattern and this causes kibana-4 to search every possible index. As kibana-4 has its own **.kibana** index, it tries to search for the required data in .kibana index and since it doesn't parse the data there it throws some parsing exceptions. So Is there any way by which I can configure kibana-4 to exclude .kibana for searching..

Answer (score 8):

I was able to successfully ignore the `.kibana` index by using the following
request:

```
curl 'localhost:9200/*,-*kibana/_search?q=*:*'
```

This will search all indices (the first "*") excluding all indices that end with
"kibana".

Comment: Thanx for the suggestion, but this only works for queries manually written using command-line, I am looking for a query to do this in Kibana 4 using the Discover option..

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own alias similar to _all and use it in kibana. Or you could just exclude .kibana index from _all index alias.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. In query you can exclude some them like this:

```
"filter": {
    "bool": {
        "must_not": {
            "term": {
                "_index": "<the_index_you_want_to_exclude>"
            }
        }
    }
}
```